# Application name; space between words, or no space?

Tags: wording

I am trying to determine what convention I should use to name my application.

I am developing a Web Browser and I know this will seem like a weird thing to ask, but please bear with me.

More and more now, I keep seeing companies releasing software with names like *FindMe*, *OneDrive* or *SkyDrive* for example, where both words are joined together as if they are a single word. Also, sometimes each word is a different color than the one it is joined to, or sometimes, instead of being different colors, one word is bold, while the other is regular.

**How should I write my application name?**

I am asking this here instead of the English site because I would like to know whether this affects the UX of my application. Which is preferred out of these two:

- MyBrowser,
  or
- My Browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the name is made up of two common words, then putting them together like "MyBrowser" will make it much easier for customers to find you. Otherwise, search engines will look for both words as separate tokens and return a lot more unrelated stuff.

Also, having the words together clearly communicates that your name is a name and not a description or tag line, so it creates stronger brand recognition.

Comment: Interesting points, but please reference research for your answer.

Comment: Also, if you use a space, this could lead to some confusion when someone is talking about it, likt in the Abbott and Costello sketch "Who's on First"  A:Please open My Browser  B: your Browser?  A: No not your Browser, my Browser!  B: That's what I said!